# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name 'Manager1Factory' not found in context ''

Tags: hibernate, jboss7.x

I get the error

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name 'Manager1Factory' not found in context ''
```

when I try to deploy my hibernate app in JBoss 7.  The line of code that is throwing this exception looks like

```
    entityManagerFactory = (EntityManagerFactory)ctx.lookup("java:/Manager1Factory");
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
```

I have the JNDI name defined in persistence.xml like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-    instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary2">
      <!-- If you are running in a production environment, add a managed 
         data source, the example data source is just for proofs of concept! -->
      <!-- We may want to make this a jta-data-source and let the container create     entityManagers/look up EntityManagers via JNDI in our business objs -->
      <non-jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS2</non-jta-data-source>      
          <class>com.mycompany.myapp.anywhere.common.businessobjects.CurrentTransaction</class>               
  <class>com.mycompany.myapp.anywhere.common.businessobjects.ServerSettings</class>               
  <class>com.mycompany.myapp.anywhere.common.persistence.HibernateUtil</class>           

  <properties>
     <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
     <!-- <sproperty name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" /> -->
     <!-- <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" /> -->
     <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
     <property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor.session_scoped" value="com.mycompany.myapp.anywhere.common.persistence.BusinessObjectInterceptor"/>
     <property name="jboss.entity.manager.jndi.name" value="java:/Manager1"/>           
     <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/Manager1Factory"/>  
     </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I'm not sure why I'm receiving this error - when I check the JBoss console I see the name Manager1Factory shows up under JNDI bindings, so it seems like the EntityManagerFactory is being created but it is not being injected into my class?  Any ideas why this is happening?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:jboss/Manager1Factory"/>
```

and

```
java:jboss/Manager1Factory
```